# Showing specific taxonomy term always at the end

Tags: php, wordpress, taxonomy-terms

I have a custom post type called Jobs, and it includes also custom taxonomy work-category. So far I was displaying my content in the following way (that works):

```
<div class="col-lg-10">
    <?php
    $terms = get_terms([
    'taxonomy' => 'work-category',
    'hide_empty' => true,
    'orderby'  => 'count',
    'order' => 'DESC',
    ]);


    if ($terms) {
    foreach ($terms as $category) { ?>

        <h2 class="category-h2">
            <?= $category->name ?>
        </h2>


        <?php
        $posts = get_posts(array(
            'posts_per_page'    => -1,
            'post_type'         => 'jobs',
            'tax_query' => [
            [
                'taxonomy' => 'work-category',
                'field' => 'term_id',
                'terms' => $category->term_id,
            ]
            ]
        ));

        if ( $posts ) {
            foreach( $posts as $post ) {
            setup_postdata( $post );
            include 'WorkView.php';
            };
            wp_reset_postdata();
        }

    }
    } else { //no categories

    $posts = get_posts(array(
        'posts_per_page'    => -1,
        'post_type'         => 'career'
    ));

    if ( $posts ) {
        foreach( $posts as $post ) {
        setup_postdata( $post );
        include 'JobListThumb.php';
        };
        wp_reset_postdata();
    }

    }
    ?>

</div>
```

I've decided to add one more featured called "show always at the end". And for that I have created a custom field (name: stick_to_end), dedicated only to terms from this specific taxonomy (work-category). So simply what I'm trying to achieve is to show all works categories and order them by count BUT on still show specific one at the very end (so sth like sticky posts/category but the other way around). What I've already tried was:

```
1. An array in orderby so `'orderby'  => array ('count' => DESC, 'stick_to_end' => ASC)`

2. meta_query
<code>
    'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key'      => 'count',
                    'value'    => EXISTS, 
                ),
                array(
                    'key'      => 'stick_to_end',
                    'compare'  => '=',
                    'value'    => false, 
                ),
            )
```

But this also doesn't work. How to achieve that or where I'm doing the mistake?

Comment: I am not sure whether this is actually not supported, as Vinay said in their answer. Check the last example under https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters, `‘orderby’ with multiple ‘meta_key’s` - using "named meta queries" appears to be the key here. And I think you will have to go with just EXIST for your stick_to_end field as well - you do not want to limit the _selection_ of posts to those that have it set to false _only_, you just want to use this field as an order criterion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ifThe `get_terms` you're using, use `WP_Term_Query` internally which doesn't support ordering by multiple keys the same way `WP_Query` does.

So here's a custom method to order them after you've queried them.

```
usort( $terms, function( $a, $b ) {
    $a_ste = (int) get_term_meta( $a->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true );
    $b_ste = (int) get_term_meta( $b->term_id, 'stick_to_end', true );

    if ($a_ste == $b_ste) return 0;
    return ($a_ste < $b_ste) ? -1 : 1;
} );
```

Place this code before `if ($terms) {`

Let me know if this worked for you.